# Windows remote access without RDP?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, remote-access

Given valid credentials for an existing non-admin user account who is not in the RDP group, is there a way to access this account without RDP?  VNC is not an option either.  Tools like psexec (in different flavours) apparently don't work (or I didn't understand how to use them).

Comment: Has the account been granted remote login rights?

Comment: This question is too broad for SuperUser. Please edit the question and redefine your question so an answer can be given that has not many possibilities. (See the help->Help Center on how to ask a question).

Comment: @grawity: the user is not in the RDP goup.

Answer (score 1):

There are way too many possibilities to do that.
If you'd like to access Desktop than use open sourced [UltraVnc](http://www.uvnc.com/), it has ability authenticate over regular credentials, but my advice is to install encryption plugin and use asymmetric cryptographic keys to protect traffic and made it impossible to brute force.

If you need console access, then the most reliable way is to install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and activate `ssh` daemon(also support public key authentication) that used for decades on Unix based system to remotely manage computers. Cygwin environment allows you to use both - windows programs and Unix based powerful utilities.

Comment: There are a number of free alternatives to set up a Windows system as an [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) server. I've used [Bitvise SSH Server](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server), [Copssh](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/Copssh501/), which makes use of Cygwin, [freeSSHd](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/network/ssh/freeSSHd/), and [PowerShell SSH Server](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/ssh/PSSrvr6/). UltraVNC is good for VNC; there's also [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/)

Comment: Just to add to that list I personally use and recommend teamviewer as it can run without being installed. So no admin rights required to get it working. Edit: free for personal use. If you are using it to access your corporate or business resources you may need to purchase a license.